# Angular "build --prod" issue "Property is private and only accessible within class"

Tags: angular-cli, angular-components

So I am fairly new to Angular(around 2 weeks).
I have been running my local server using "ng -serve" which works perfectly and data is inserted into the table as intended.

But when I try to make a build for prod "ng build --prod" it gives me an error

```
Error at C:/Users/AngularProject/src/app/subjectc2/subjectc2.component.html(1,141): Property 'componentModelService' does not exist on type 'subjectc2Component'.
```

So I have a component which accesses a variable from another service.
Attaching file structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ig21.png)

I added the folder structure as my service is in the root folder unlike the components.

I imported the service using

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentsModelService } from '../components-model.service';
@Component({
   selector: 'subjectc2',
   templateUrl: './subjectc2.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./subjectc2.component.css']
})
export class subjectc2Component implements OnInit {

   constructor(private componentModelService: ComponentsModelService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

}
```

I have tried removing the "public"/"private" keyword

Service File:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ComponentsModelService {
JSONObject = {};
constructor() {
    this.JSONObject = {
        //Big Ass JSON
        };

}
submitIsClicked(event){
    var Responsepayload = {
        //Small ass JSON
    }
    //DO SomthhingHere
};
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code the error refers to. You have `private` in some other place.

Comment: Added Code, All code can't be shown

Comment: You need to change `private` to `public`. Not remove it.